# What is the equilibrium distribution for the Lattice Boltzman Model on a hexagonal grid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations

I'm trying to implement a lattice Boltzmann model fluid simulation, but I'm having trouble implementing it right now.

Every source I find seems to give a different equilibrium distribution and I don't really understand which one is correct. If I try to research any more I just keep collecting more and more functions for the distribution (I have at least $5$ right now), so I don't really know where to go from here.
Some include free parameters, others do not.

I think that it is safe to say that my current program does not work as intended, because below is pictured the best results that I got so far:

[Random initial condition and a dense region in the middle of the lattice](https://i.ibb.co/mBnK4Rx/fluidfail.gif)

I would be grateful for any help or tips. Again, my question is:

**What is the equilibrium distribution for the Lattice Boltzman Model on a hexagonal grid?**

My definitions, pseudocode and references follow below:

---

### Program

```
UpdateLattice:
   foreach site in Lattice
       UpdateSite(site)
   Lattice = Buffer

UpdateSite(site):
   for i from 0 to 6
       Update(site, i)
    
Update(site, i):
   Buffer(Neighbor(site, i), i) = (1+lambda) * N_i(site) - lambda * N_eq(site, i)

Neighbor(x, i)
   return x + c_i
```

lambda is the lattice spacing, N_i are the population densities and N_eq are the equilibrium distributions

### Definitions

Lattice site: $\textbf{x}$

Population densities: $N_i(\textbf{x}, t)$

Density: $\rho(\textbf{x},t) = \sum_{i=0}^{6}N_i(\textbf{x},t)$

Velocities: $\textbf{c}_i = \cases{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\left((i-1)\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cr\sin\left((i-1)\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\end{pmatrix} & $i\gt 0$ \cr\cr \begin{pmatrix}0\cr0\end{pmatrix} & $i=0$}$

Velocity : $\textbf{u}(\textbf{x}, t) = \frac{1}{\rho(\textbf{x},t)} \sum_{i=0}^{6}N_i(\textbf{x},t)\textbf{c}_i$

---

### Reference 1

I tried following *"Lattice-Gas Cellular Automata" (Rothman and Zaleski)*, but I'm having trouble. Here's the definitions they use:

$$N_i^{(p)} = f \left( 1 + \frac{c_{i\alpha} u_{\alpha}}{c_s^2} + u_{\alpha} u_{\beta} (G_m Q_{i\alpha\beta}+G_c c^2 \delta_{\alpha\beta})\right)$$
$$N_0^{(p)}=f(b_c-b_m G_c c^2 u^2)$$

With $Q_{i\alpha\beta}=c_{i\alpha}c_{i\beta}-\frac{c^2}{D}\delta_{\alpha\beta}$

Where $D$ is the dimension of the model ($2$ in this case) and reduced density $f=\frac{\rho}{b}$.

$b=b_m+b_c$, where $b_m$ is the number of unit velocities ($6$) and $b_c$ is a free parameter that is chosen to be $4.0$ for "stability reasons" (according to [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/latticegas-cellular-automata/46A8F33A6BF79F46899E9271074D6588)).

$G_c= \frac{\rho b}{c_s^4 b_m}$ and $G_m=\frac{D(D+2)b\rho}{2c_s^4 b_m}$

With $c_s^2=\frac{b_m c^2}{bD}$ and $c=|c_i|=1$

I'm guessing that $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is supposed to be the Kronecker-Delta, but I don't understand what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are doing in its subscript here... $c_{i\alpha}$ is the $x$-component of the $i$th velocity vector (I think), but what it means in this case, I don't know. What would make sense to me is $\delta{c_{i\alpha} c_{i\beta}}$, but I'm not sure that is it...

---

### Reference 2

Another book that I have followed successfully in the past for the D2Q9 model is *"Cellular Automata Modeling of Physical Systems" (Chopard and Droz - [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/216300438_Cellular_Automata_Modeling_of_Physical_Systems)).*
They also give a equilibrium distribution for the hexagonal lattice, but it looks pretty different from the one above. This one also includes the Kronecker-Delta part I don't understand:

$$N_i^{(p)}=\frac{\rho}{12}\left[  1  +   \frac{4}{v^2} v_i \cdot u   +  8 \frac{u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}}{v^4} \left(  v_{i\alpha}v_{i\beta} - \frac{v^2}{4}\delta_{\alpha\beta}  \right)    \right]$$
$$N_0^{(p)}=\frac{\rho}{2}\left[  1 - 2 \frac{u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}}{v^2}  \right]$$